# How can i get reference from this object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, object, constructor, reference

can someone explain whats going on? I just make object by constructor and pass through it virtual camera to effect. However im getting error like as virtual camera never created.

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
> CameraManager+ShakeEffect..ctor (Cinemachine.CinemachineVirtualCamera cinemachineVirtualCamera) (at Assets/Scripts/CameraManager.cs:27)
> CameraManager.Awake () (at Assets/Scripts/CameraManager.cs:13)
>
> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
> CameraManager+ShakeEffect.Effect () (at Assets/Scripts/CameraManager.cs:31)
> Health.SetHealth (System.Int32 value) (at Assets/Scripts/Health/Health.cs:22)
> SpiderAI.OnTriggerEnter (UnityEngine.Collider col) (at Assets/AiScript/Spider/SpiderAI.cs:27)

```
 public class CameraManager : MonoBehaviour
 {
 
     private CinemachineVirtualCamera cinemachineVirtualCamera;
     private void Awake()
     {
         cinemachineVirtualCamera = GetComponent<CinemachineVirtualCamera>();
         var shakeEffect = new ShakeEffect(cinemachineVirtualCamera);
         GetComponent<Health>().OnGetDamage += shakeEffect.Effect;
     }
 
     public class ShakeEffect : ICameraEffect
     {
 
         private float duration = 5f;
         private float intensity = 2f;
 
         public CinemachineVirtualCamera cinemachineVirtualCamera;
 
         public ShakeEffect(CinemachineVirtualCamera cinemachineVirtualCamera) {
             this.cinemachineVirtualCamera = cinemachineVirtualCamera;
         }
 
         public void Effect()
         {
             CinemachineBasicMultiChannelPerlin cinemachineBasicMultiChannelPerlin =
                 cinemachineVirtualCamera.GetCinemachineComponent<CinemachineBasicMultiChannelPerlin>();
 
             cinemachineBasicMultiChannelPerlin.m_AmplitudeGain = intensity;
             StopShake(cinemachineBasicMultiChannelPerlin);
         }
 
         private void StopShake(CinemachineBasicMultiChannelPerlin cinemachineBasicMultiChannelPerlin)
         {
 
             var elapsedTime = 0f;
 
             while (duration < elapsedTime)
             {
                 elapsedTime += Time.time;
             }
             cinemachineBasicMultiChannelPerlin.m_AmplitudeGain = 0f;
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear as the line numbers don't match up.

I guess GetComponent() is failing to find that "Health" component in Awake. So it's probably missing on that game object.

Comment: its impossible, health component is attached to gameobject. but you re quite right, i copied wrong error. Problem happen when enemy with SpiderAI script, detect collision with player. Health component is just event handler. and when SetHealth component is triggered it also trigger OnGetDamage event.

Comment: With the updated answer it looks like it's whatever is at Assets/AiScript/Spider/SpiderAI.cs:27 now

If it's still showing both errors, the way the relationships are setup between the components could be disrupted. Errors in Awake can cause odd things to happen.